# How to download Play! Framework dependencies before test phase?

Tags: playframework

I have certain webjar dependencies (requirejs, jQuery, angular etc.) that I would like Play 2.3.x to download into target folder before test phase so that I can use them in jasmine unit tests. Dependencies are defined in build.sbt and they are now downloaded only in dist phase; so jasmine tests that are run in test phase cannot use them.

Is there a way to download certain or all dependencies in Play! 2.3.x before test phase?  I use maven for build and can configure custom activator tasks (if there is any) to run before test phase.

Alternative to this will be to configure jasmine tests to be run during verify phase, but these are unit tests and I would like them to be run in test phase.

Comment: How do you define these dependencies currently?

Comment: @RichDougherty Dependencies are defined in [build.sbt](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SBTDependencies).

Comment: I was hoping you'd paste the code you use to define dependencies so I could look at the code and see if anything looked wrong. sbt-web has introduced new classifiers but I'm not sure if you need them.

Comment: @RichDougherty There is nothing special in defining deps, it is very similar to the samples in playframework link I posted in my previous response.  Here is a (partial) snippet: `libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.webjars" % "requirejs" % "2.1.14-2",
  "org.webjars" % "jquery" % "2.1.1",
)`

Answer (score 0):

I would go with

```
activator update
activator stage
activator test
```

Command "update" will download all dependencies, "stage" will generate project files into target directory without generating zip package (I use it for jenkins deployment after running tests) and finally I run tests.

Comment: Thanks.  Stage step in fact packages the app, running all the requirejs minifications and this step takes a long time.  Currently I am running `activator dist` during maven process-test-resources lifecycle stage. IMHO, dist is slightly better than stage as dist does not leave the target/universal folder behind, instead it creates a single zip file with the required binaries. I was trying to avoid the full packaging step before the javascript sources are validated with unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

In Play 2.5.3, `activator test` downloads dependencies into target folder before running tests. Not sure if this came in a previous version.  I do not need to do `activator dist` before running tests that required webjar dependencies.